# How can i make a div stay next to a specifc element in all Screens types with HTML, CSS and Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having struggles with what I'm trying to acomplish. Basicly I have 2 colums in my HTML and on my left colum I have text and want to have div's on the right colum with videos stay near certain parts of the text. Diferent aproaches I have tried are table cells, who I couldn' make work how I wanted because it would deformat the text creating big spaces between paragraphs to fit in the size of the video on the right. 
I have also tried dummy divs to fill the vertical space but this won't work for all screens since the div's sizes will be diferent. 
I've tried searching for some anchors that could be attached to the text somehow where I could create a div next to it without influencing the text itself but I'm kinda lost.
I hope this question is according to the rules. Thanks in advance.

[image in paint to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c022c.png)

Comment: Do you really have to create two columns? It sounds like you're making it yourself a lot harder then it should be. Also, could you add the relevant HTML code to your post?

Comment: None of it was kinda working as I wanted so I don't really have a code to show I can make a drawing/picture real fast :v. As for the columns. I want it to be side by side they dont have to be 2 columns if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link and let me know whether you want this type of layout

```css
.row {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
.bg-red {
  background: red;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
       <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <video width="100%" height="300" controls>
          <source   src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-red">
    <div class="col-6">
     
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremq natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <video width="100%" height="300" controls>
          <source   src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The concept is exactly this but my problem now is that I want to be able to place the video where I want it in that column and not just in the middle of it.

Comment: For the class row, I have given the property align-items. For that i have given flex-end as value to move at the end of column. Check all the values for css align-items to move wherever you need. If it doesn't work use position:absolute.

Comment: wont position absolute be hard to position for diferent screen resolutions?

Comment: Then use align-items property with css values available to change the position